# How to Mitigate Snowball Effect of Events

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

I enjoy the events thematically, but the majority of them seem to be of the general form: Make a [stat] roll. If you succeed, increase [stat], if you fail, decrease [stat].

Because the number of dice you get to roll are based on your current stat value, you're more likely to succeed and increase some stat that you're already good at, and more likely to fail and decrease some stat that you're already bad at.

Especially during the exploration phase, there is little to do except explore new rooms and get hit with unpredictable events which will increasingly cripple you if you have a lower-than-average stat.

Does anyone know of a way to mitigate this snowball effect, so you're not perpetually punished for having a bad roll early?

**Edit**: More specifically, I was looking for additions to the rules that provide a little more agency/forgiveness than conservative gameplay, which tends to rely on the cooperation of others.

Comment: Only 5 of the 45 Event cards (as far as I can see) force stat penalties on the same stat as the initial roll. Most deal physical or mental damage, meaning you almost always have two stats to choose from when taking the hit.

Comment: Interesting; I thought it was more common than that, but maybe my roommate has phenomenally bad luck. Maybe it's some of the rooms (like the Junk Room, I believe it's called) which contribute to this feeling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do to make it less likely you'll get crippled:

- Pick a character with balanced starting stats - **Brandon Jaspers**, **Peter Akimoto**, **Jenny LeClerc** and **Madam Zostra** all start with three of their stats on 4 and the 4th on 3.
- When a room that boosts your stats (Chapel, Gymnasium, Larder, Library) appears, make your way there immediately if the haunt hasn't started yet (if the haunt has already started you may have more important things to do).

While I love the game it is pretty random and you have to accept that sometimes you get screwed. It's worth pointing out that you can't die until the haunt starts, in case you missed that rule.

Comment: Glad that you brought up that you can't die until the haunt starts. And once it does, there is a good chance that the traitor, if there is one, has also been affected by reduced stats, which helps the investigators.

Comment: It's not much better to be one stat above dead when the haunt starts. And it's not in the best interests of the person who discovers a stat-boosting room to wait for everyone else to be able to access it; maybe my group is too selfish from the get-go.

Comment: @HammerBro., it's common for the person who finds the stat-boosting room to keep exploring. But, if all of the other players immediately *stop* exploring to rush to the stat-boosting room, then it's unlikely that the single exploring player is going to start the haunt. All players might not get to all stat-boosting rooms before the haunt starts, but most players should get to most of the stat-boosting rooms.